# Get user who upvotes server on top.gg

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, webhooks

How do I get the user data when someone upvotes a server. The docs only specifics when someone upvotes a bot. Is there a way do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is a super simple task with Flask. You can just setup a `/webhook` domain extension that uses `POST`.

```
@app.route("/webhook", methods=["POST"])
def respond():
    print(request.json);
    # TODO
```

If you’ve never used Flask before, [this is a great mega-guide to the whole module](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world). You can run it simultaneously with your bot using [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html). These two modules are extremely useful to learn and are great experience for any Python programmer. However, they are quite difficult to master and even more so to use together. If you need any help with this in the future, don’t hesitate to ask StackOverflow!

Comment: Hi there! Could you please explain what you mean by ` You can just setup a /webhook domain extension that uses POST`. I'm new to webhooks and can use all the help i can get

Comment: Hello Aryan! Thanks for reaching out and in hindsight, I probably should have provided a bit more explanation in my answer. Webhooks are methods for other applications to send you data via a POST request. In the example I gave, Flask opened a webhook and printed the JSON data whenever it was accessed. In the case of top.gg, they send the person who voted. That mega tutorial I linked in the original answer can help you to master Flask and my example can easily help you create your own webhook. If you have any other questions, don’t hesitate to contact me!